# Format of Generic methods with generic returns

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I would like to implement a function that returns a value of the type it is operating on.  How do I accomplish this please?

Example 1:

```
static T Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
{
    T temp;
    temp = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = temp;

    return <T> temp;
}
```

Example 2:

```
public override T GetRandom()
{
    return  (T)_random.Next(_min, _max);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "value of the time"?

Comment: even if there is no reason to return, just returning temp without any cast works, since temp is already declared to be 'T'. Btw your cast is wrong sintatycally (T) is correct, but useless.

Comment: I meant value of the type being worked on. I do have other example there that will better explain what I am asking of.

Comment: The second example you add is fundamentally completely unrelated to the first example.

Answer (score 7):

Since both the return-type and the variable-type are already `T`, this is just:

```
return temp;
```

Alternatively, to cast (but this is not needed here):

```
return (T) temp;
```

Actually, though, IMO a "swap" should have `void` return!

Comment: I just added the 2nd example of what I need to do above. In that case, it does not seem to be correct syntax. How do I best deal with such a situation, assuming my T are numerals.

Comment: @user272671 your "random" example is not going to work. Ever. That isn't a "generic"-style cast. What you are trying to do there is a **conversion**. The only way to do that is probably `return (T)Convert.ChangeType(theNextValue, typeof(T));` which is pretty inefficient, but will work for a few types (float, decimal, etc). It is ***not***, however, a "generic" thing.

Answer (score 0):

it makes no sense to make this generic:

```
public override T GetRandom()
{
     return  (T)_random.Next(_min, _max);
}
```

what is meant by random "T"?  Suppose T is of type "Person", what is meant by returning random Person? There just doesn't seem to be any logic in having a generic GetRandom method.

If you want an integer just specify int as the return type.

```
public override int GetRandom()
{
    return  _random.Next(_min, _max); 
}
```